# "IsAsync" has no effect for slow property?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, asynchronous, viewmodel

I have a slow data source, so I create it asynchronously. Also, many properties of my viewmodel are themselves slow. Hence, I make them asynchronous too (binding to a Telerik property grid):

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.DataContext>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type viewModels:MyViewModel}"
      IsAsynchronous="True" x:Name="myViewModel" />
  </Grid.DataContext>
  <telerik:RadPropertyGrid x:Name="settings" Item="{Binding IsAsync=True}">
    <telerik:RadPropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
      <telerik:PropertyDefinition
        Binding="{Binding Path=SlowProperty,IsAsync=True,Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </telerik:RadPropertyGrid.PropertyDefinitions>
  </telerik:RadPropertyGrid>
</Grid>
```

When debugging, I can see that the data source is indeed created in another thread, hence not blocking the UI. However, when I get into `SlowProperty` the debugger reveals that I'm still in the Main Thread - which is proven by the fact that the UI hangs until the property returns.

**Q:** What am I missing here? Isn't `IsAsync` sufficient for asynchronous properties?

**Edit:** It seems this works for a normal `TextBlock`. Is the `IsAsync` behavior dependent on the implementation of a control? (In this case I suspect a bug in the property grid.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are always ecouraged to use `IsAsync` `Binding` with `PriorityBinding`. GUI will wait until property is executed. But with `PriorityBinding` it will check if the first `Binding` property is `slow`, if so, it will select the next **placeholder** binding (which should be fast). But when the slow property is evaluated, it would become the active value by the binding.

```
<TextBlock>
 <TextBlock.Text>
  <PriorityBinding FallbackValue="defaultvalue">
    <Binding Path="SlowestProp" IsAsync="True"/>
    <Binding Path="SlowerProp" IsAsync="True"/>
    <Binding Path="SurelyFastProp" />
  </PriorityBinding>
 </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

In your case, you can simply set some `defaultValue` instead of giving multiple bindings.

Comment: Are you saying that `PriorityBinding` is crucial for asynchronous binding?